# Platform Stripe automatic payout to connected stripe accounts not working - No such external account

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I am having some weird issue when I try to payout to my platforms connected accounts, below is sample code of how I payout to connected account where "source" is a test connected account "acct_1IE4WnG9fsPmbonD" used as destination to my payout parameter

```
PayoutCreateParams payoutCreateParams = PayoutCreateParams.builder()
            .setAmount(amount).setDestination(source)
            .setCurrency(currency).build();
    RequestOptions options = RequestOptions
            .builder()
            .setIdempotencyKey(uuid)
            .setApiKey(stripeKey)
            .build();
    Payout payout = Payout.create(payoutCreateParams, options);
```

When I try to execute this I get an error saying

```
com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException:
No such external account: 'acct_1IE4WnG9fsPmbonD'; code: resource_missing; request-id: req_vnLHhOn3WaG9IT
```

My use case is basically to payout to may platforms connected account maybe twice a month.

So Now I wonder if I am doing payout to my platform connected account wrong!.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A Payout is meant to go to a bank account or debit card, not a Stripe Account.  You probably want Transfers, not Payouts: https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers

Alternatively, you would want to use a bank account ID in `setDestination` if required, and then include the Stripe-Account header to make an actual payout: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/manual-payouts#regular-payouts